# Byte array to 32 bit floating point in Julia

Tags: floating-point, julia

I have a byte array in Julia:

```
a = [0x41,0x40,0x00,0x00]
```

which is the 32 bit floating point byte representation of decimal number 12.0.

32 bit IEEE 754 representation of 12.0 is '0x41400000'.

I have two questions:

1. How can I convert this array `a` to Float32 number 12.0 ?
2. Reverse : How can I convert this Float32 number 12.0 to byte array [0x41,0x40,0x00,0x00] ?

I have tried `reinterpret(Float32,[12.0])` and `reinterpret(UInt32,[12.0])`. No success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number `12.0` is a `Float64`, which you shouldn't be mixing into this. `12f0` is the `Float32` version of this. It seems you are doing things a bit backwards.

Here's how you reinterpret `12f0` into bytes:

```
jl> a = reinterpret(UInt8, [12f0])
4-element reinterpret(UInt8, ::Vector{Float32}):
 0x00
 0x00
 0x40
 0x41
```

(Notice that you had the order of bytes backwards in your array `a`.) And here's the other way:

```
jl> reinterpret(Float32, a)
1-element Vector{Float32}:
 12.0
```

or

```
jl> reinterpret(Float32, [0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x41])
1-element reinterpret(Float32, ::Vector{UInt8}):
 12.0
```

The printing of `12f0` as `12.0` is a bit unfortunate, since it's the wrong literal, but the type tag is clear, at least.